# Share notebooks across Azure Machine learning service notebook VM

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there any way to share a Azure notebook across multiple users who use different notebook VMs? It seems the VMs itself is not shareable across users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notebook VMs has own Jupyter environment and we don't need to use notebooks.azure.com. The former can be used in enterprise scenarios within the team to share the resources, and the latter is open, similar to google colab. When each user login to his notebook VM, there is a top level folder with his/her alias and under that all notebooks are stored. this is stored in an Azure storage and each user's notebook VM will mount same storage. Hence If I want to view other person \'s notebook, I need to navigate to his alias in the Jupyter nb in my nbvm

Answer (score 3):

Azure Machine Learning Notebook VM is a part of Azure Machine Learning service, whereas jupyter notebooks on Azure Machine Learning Studio are the part of the Notebook service that runs on Ubuntu 14.04.02 under Docker. With Jupyter in Azure ML Stuido you have the full Anaconda 64-bit distribution available to you.

Thus, if you are willing to share the Azure ML Studio notebook you will need to add a user to your workspace with owner rights.

Comment: I refer to Azure machine learning service, not studio. From the Notebook VM, the docs mentions the notebooks are shareable. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: Ok, great! As there was an aml studio hashtag I prefered to clarify beforehand to avoid any confusion. So I am trying to understand the problem : you have your Jupyter notebook and you are willing to share it across multiple users, right? In this case you may provide them a link to your notebook and they will be able to clone it to their own Azure Notebooks workspace. If they don't have one they will be prompted to create an account. Does this solve your issue? I will post a separate answer to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at [this example](https://notebooks.azure.com/ms-ai/projects/Text-Lab) there is a clone button. So when, say, Microsoft DataScientist shares his code all the others may clone his notebook to their own workspace.

After they clone it the url is no longer

> https://notebooks.azure.com/ms-ai/projects/Text-Lab/html/Text%20Lab%20-%20workflow%20and%20embedding.ipynb

but

> https://notebooks.azure.com/another-user-workspace/projects/Text-Lab/html/Text%20Lab%20-%20workflow%20and%20embedding.ipynb

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Finally I figured out the solution. Notebook VMs has own Jupyter environment  and we don't need to use http://notebooks.azure.com. The former can be used in enterprise scenarios within the team to share the resources, and the latter is open, similar to google colab. When each user login to his notebook VM, there is a top level folder with his/her alias and under that all notebooks are stored. this is stored in an Azure storage and each user's notebook VM will mount same storage. Hence If I want to view other person \'s notebook, I need to navigate to his alias in the Jupyter nb in my nbvm.

Comment: Great! So why don't you post the answer to your own question? This would be helpful for the other users too.